# Are the spacelike foliations of a non-static spacetime topologically equivalent?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, topology

Assuming a stationary, globally hyperbolic spacetime, I can imagine that all spacelike foliations are topologically equivalent though not all will be identical since the spacetime is not static. Is there a proof of this somewhere? If not, could somebody give me a rigorous argument please?

Comment: I'm afraid not! https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353148/is-de-sitter-space-with-non-zero-curvature-an-acceptable-model-for-the-universe/353157#353157

Comment: Is the question whether all slices in a spacelike foliation have the same topology, or that the slices of all possible foliations have the same topology?

Comment: @Slereah this is very helpful thank you very much.