Are de Sitter, Anti-de Sitter and Minkowski spaces spatially infinite?
I am not someone who has studied general relativity, however have recently developed an interest in it. From what I have seen online, de Sitter, Minkowski and Anti-de Sitter spaces are often compared to a sphere, a plane and a hyperbolic paraboloid. Since a sphere in 2D would be finite and the plane and hyperbolic paraboloid infinite, would the same be true for de Sitter, Minkowski and Anti-de Sitter spaces? In other words, would de Sitter spaces be spatially finite at any given moment of time and Minkowski and Anti-de Sitter spaces be spatially infinite?

Yes, that's correct.

No, this is not correct. See for example this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/353157/386743

@SethK So from what I understand, for de Sitter spaces, the properties of the space are conserved regardless of whether it is spatially finite or infinite? Would the same be true for Minkowski and Anti-de Sitter space?
